# Почему возникает ошибки при установки java-alternatives?

Tags: java, debian, openjdk, java-11, jdk11

Хочу что бы JDK11 был выбран, по умолчанию, вручную. Ввожу команду:

```
 sudo update-java-alternatives --list
```

Мне выдает две версии 8 и 11

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Далее выбираю java 11.

```
 sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 --verbose
```

И начинают сыпаться ошибки.

```
resetting java alternatives
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для appletviewer
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для extcheck
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для idlj
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для javah
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для jhat
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для jsadebugd
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для mozilla-javaplugin.so
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для native2ascii
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для policytool
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для schemagen
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для wsgen
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для wsimport
update-alternatives: ошибка: нет альтернатив для xjc
```

Подозреваю нет альтернатив потому что этих компонентов просто нет в новой джаве, но тогда откуда они взялись?

ОС Дебиан.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как видно из содержимого запускаемого скрипта `/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives`, список [альтернатив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives) черпается из файлов `/usr/lib/jvm/.*.jinfo`, которые находятся в пакетах:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/.*.jinfo
openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
```

перечислены там альтернативы для файлов всех пакетов типа `openjdk-версия-*`. у вас же явно пакеты с *jdk* (`*-версия-jdk*`) не установлены (это в них входят все эти `appletviewer` и т.п.)

вообще эти сообщения, насколько я вижу, не влияют на результат выполнения скрипта: альтернативы (для существующих файлов) успешно заменяются.

но чтобы сообщений не было, надо добавить опцию, которая отфильтрует альтернативы только для нужных пакетов: `--jre` или `--jre-headless`.

например:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives --jre --set java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: то есть нужно доустановить те пакеты которые требуются? (в которые входят appletviewer и т.п.) и тогда перестанет появляться ошибки?

Comment: 1. если пакеты не нужны — не устанавливайте. 2. об этом весь ответ. особенно его концовка.